# PTIJ: Rapunzel covering her hair

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How would Rapunzel cover her hair after getting married, assuming she's Jewish?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Get a haircut, perhaps?

Comment: But then she wouldn't be Rapunzel. Rapunzel is by definition a princess with extremely long hair.

Comment: Tzvei dinim in Rapunzel: Rapunzel the person is a regular ol' princess. Rapunzel the fairy-tale character is a princess with super-long hair. Even if Rapunzel the fairy-tale character disappears, you're still left with Rapunzel the regular person.

Comment: With a Shuper Sheitel from Sheitelbaum's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She should get a Thneed- it's a fine something that all people need! They're durable and versatile and can easily be made into a giant head covering.

https://seuss.fandom.com/wiki/Thneed

Answer (score 3):

[Snoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snood_(headgear)) are amazing - at least this is what almost every one of my female married friends tell me. (My wife disagrees, but, there's a separate reason for that.)

Snoods are flexible, durable and, best of all, extandable and sizeable. I would imagine that Rapunzel's snood would probably have to be the size of a huge trash bag, but, so what? Best of all, as Rapunzel's hair grows longer, it is easy to stretch the snood or just add more yarn / fabric to make it bigger.